# SwiftUI - How to add button as a navigation title?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image]

Is it possible to make the navbar title clickable like a button?
Tried `.navigationBarTitle(Button(....))`, but this won’t work bc button doesn't conform to string protocol...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]Here is a possible solution

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geo in
            
                List {
                    
                Text("Have a nice day!")
                Text("Today is sunny")
                
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: HStack{
                    
                    Spacer().frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.5)
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text("Title")
                        Button(action: {
                            print("I'm feeling lucky ;)")
                        })
                        {
                            Text("Button")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Spacer().frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.5)
                })
            }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If only this also allowed to still have a leading button...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in this answer](https://In%20iOS%2014%20SwiftUI%20you%20can%20customise%20a%20View%20navigation%20bar%20title%20with%20the%20toolbar%20modifier,%20set%20ToolbarItem%20of%20placement%20type%20.principal%20to%20a%20new%20toolbar%20modifier.), from iOS 14 onwards, the `toolbar` view modifier can be used to place a `ToolBarItem` in the navigation bar. A [ToolBarItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritem) can be any view that conforms to the `ToolbarContent` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbarcontent).

**Note:** If you want to make the toolbar content appear in place of the navigation title, make sure to set the `placement` parameter as `.principal`. Here is an example:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button {
            // Your button action here
        } label: {
            // your button label here
            Text("I am a button")
        }
    }
            
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> You can not create a button on NavigationTitle in SwiftUI Navigation View
>
> Solution: You have to create custom Navigation Bar & Other Views